# How functional languages deal with immutable data before Phil Bagwell's HAMT idea?

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, immutability

Like the question, I think persistent data structures are based on the idea of Phil Bagwell about Hash Array Mapped Trie (HAMT), which was discovered in 2001.

So, before that, how do people make data immutable without using HAMT?

Comment: *Clojure's* persistent data structures are (AFAIK) based on Bagwell's HAMTs, which are not themselves persistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the premise of your question is mistaken. The HAMT was not the first persistent data structure. For example, the landmark paper [*Making Data Structures Persistent*](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Esleator/papers/another-persistence.pdf) by Driscoll, Sarnak, and Tarjan was published in 1986, building on a large number of previous papers that had been published before in different contexts. Some of those settings include purely functional programming languages, where all (technically, most) data structures are persistent.